# How many I-frames are in a single shot?

Tags: video, video-capture, keyframes

I have some fundamental questions on shots and I-frames. When we apply shot detection on a video, how many I-frames will exist in a shot? How many frames exist between two I-frames? And does the shot always start with an I-frame?

Comment: It depends on the length of the shot, and the capture device and its settings. The GOP length(the length between I-frames) is not set in stone, it is one of the settings that can be adjusted when compressing video, and it can change within a shot. Perhaps you could specify what you're using to capture the video.

Comment: It's basically some movies, and I don't know the capture device. And I use FFmpeg to spli it into shots. I just realized it's more than 1s.